# Vagrant + symfony2 ContentErrorException file not found but file is present

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant

My Symfony2 project is throwing a exception:

Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/arne.banck/repos/Branditto_platform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

The problem is that the file is there in my folder structure, I did pwd through terminal:

```
/Users/arne.banck/repos/Branditto_platform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception
```

The following files are in this map:

```
error.atom.twig         exception.atom.twig     exception_full.html.twig
error.css.twig          exception.css.twig      logs.html.twig
error.html.twig         exception.html.twig     trace.html.twig
error.js.twig           exception.js.twig       trace.txt.twig
error.json.twig         exception.json.twig     traces.html.twig
error.rdf.twig          exception.rdf.twig      traces.txt.twig
error.txt.twig          exception.txt.twig      traces.xml.twig
error.xml.twig          exception.xml.twig      traces_text.html.twig
```

Already halted vagrant and upped again, also cleared cache already.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is in the begin of the path, what is a physical path for you destination folder? First "/" in the path means that your path is absolute and php can't find this files from the root of the system

Comment: I don't get your comment. The path that the error shows is from root and what I did is also start from root and worked my way up to the file, just like the error.

Comment: what is operating system in your vagrant box?
I mean root path of OS not  web-server or your vagrant sync folder

Comment: Still don't get it man... my vagrant boots with this -> Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64' is up to date...

Comment: and your folder Users create in root path of your Ubuntu system? If you login into your vagrant system  by type vagrant ssh in console  and after success login print cd /; ll
do you see your folder in the list?

Comment: Ye I misscomprehended your question, so I deleted my cache folder manually and that seemed to fixed the issue, thanks for helping though.